# Dynamic generation of report using RML in OpenERP

Tags: python, report, odoo, dynamic-tables, rml

How to generate dynamic columns using RML report?

Comment: @AnomA Its like a table suppose I select a month and it is january so 31 column is displayed or its february so 28 columns is displayed..!!

Answer (score 2):

Read through the developer documentation on [dynamic content in reports](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/3_11_reports/11_1_openoffice_report.html#dynamic-content-in-openoffice-reports). You can use the `repeatIn()` function to loop over your dates, but the trick will be adjusting column widths. I suspect you can change the `colWidths` attribute of the table using the `setTag()` function.

[Here's an example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zaber/openobject-addons/main/view/head:/account_reporting/report/account_report_bs.rml#L103) where I used it to change the table style.

```
    <section>
      [[ repeatIn(lines(data['form'],object=o), 'a') ]]
      <blockTable>
        [[ setTag('blockTable','blockTable',{'colWidths': '80.0,150.0,80.0', 'style': 'Table' + str(a['level'] if a['level'] &lt;= 5 else 5)}) ]] 
        <tr>
          <td lineAboveColor="#000000" lineAboveThickness="5" lineAboveCount="1" lineAboveSpace="5">
            <para style="P10"><font>[[ setTag('font','font',{'face':o.font_style or 'Helvetica', 'color':o.color_font.name or 'black', 'backColor':o.color_back.name or 'white'}) ]] [[ a['code'] ]]</font></para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="P17"><font color="white">[[ '..'*(a['level']-1) ]]</font><font>[[ setTag('font','font',{'face':o.font_style or 'Helvetica', 'color':o.color_font.name or 'black', 'backColor':o.color_back.name or 'white'}) ]] [[ a['name'] ]]</font></para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="P18"><font>[[ setTag('font','font',{'face':o.font_style or 'Helvetica', 'color':o.color_font.name or 'black', 'backColor':o.color_back.name or 'white'}) ]][[ '%.2f'% a['balance'] ]]</font></para>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </blockTable>
    </section>
```